# JQuery Call Function to Refresh Calendar

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

I was trying to modified a sample javascript/JQuery Calendar (from [https://templatemag.com/demo/Dashio/]Component/Calendar) to add events dynamically from code behind when the date is changed. Attached below are my code for the said program. I am facing below problems and hope experts here can provide some advice or suggestions.

1. How do I create the events list dynamically from c# GetData() function? Currently the details is not showing. The details will shown properly when using the remarked sample data in the script.
2. How do I call jquery showCalendar() functions to call c# GetData() and refresh the Calendar output when date changed?

Thanks in advance.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Calendar.aspx.cs" Inherits="CS_Calendar" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Calendar</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../Scripts/ds/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--external css-->
    <link href="../../Scripts/ds/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../Scripts/ds/lib/fullcalendar/bootstrap-fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../../Scripts/ds/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../Scripts/ds/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods = "true"></asp:ScriptManager> 
<!-- **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
    MAIN CONTENT
    *********************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
<!--main content start-->
<%-- <section id="main-content">--%>      
    <table >
    <tr>
        <td  ><h3><asp:Label ID="lblCaption" runat="server" Text="Calendar"></asp:Label></h3></td>
        <td style="width:50px" >&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:bottom">
            Select month
            <asp:TextBox Name="txtDate" ID="txtDate" runat="server" AutoComplete="off" ToolTip="Next service date" Width="80px" OnTextChanged="DateChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="txtDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtDate" />
            <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <section class="wrapper">                 
    <!-- page start-->
    <div class="row mt">
        <section class="panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="calendar" class="has-toolbar"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <!-- page end-->
    </section>
    <!-- /wrapper -->
    <%--</section>--%>
    <!-- /MAIN CONTENT -->
    <!--main content end-->
    </form>
</body>

<script src="../../Scripts/ds/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/ds/lib/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/ds/lib/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/ds/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/ds/lib/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/ds/lib/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/ds/lib/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--common script for all pages-->
<script src="../../Scripts/ds/lib/common-scripts.js"></script>
<!--script for this page-->
<script >
    var date = new Date($("#txtDate").val());
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ShowCalendar();
    }); 
$("#txtDate").change(function () {
    //const [dd, mm, yyyy] = $("#txtDate").val().text.split("/");
    //date.setDate(new Date(`${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`)); 
    //var sDate = $("#txtDate").text();
    date.setFullYear(2019,02,20)
    $("#lblCaption").text($("#txtDate").val());
    $("#lbl1").text($("#txtDate").val());
    ShowCalendar();
});

               
      //var Script = function () {
 function ShowCalendar() {
    /* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/                                   
    $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function () {

        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        };

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });

    });

    /* initialize the calendar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: '',   //'prev,next'
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        editable: false,
        droppable: false, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

            // render the event on the calendar
            // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
            }
        },
        events: "#<%= GetData() %>" //[
        //{
        //    title: 'All Day Event 1',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
        //},
        //{
        //    title: 'Long Event 1',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
        //    end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)
        //},
        //{
        //    id: 999,
        //    title: 'Repeating Event 1',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),
        //    allDay: false
        //},
        //{
        //    id: 999,
        //    title: 'Repeating Event',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),
        //    allDay: false
        //},
        //{
        //    title: 'Meeting',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
        //    allDay: false,
        //    url: 'http://www.google.com/'
        //},
        //{
        //    title: 'Lunch',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
        //    end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
        //    allDay: false
        //},
        //{
        //    title: 'Meeting all day',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, d),
        //    allDay: true,
        //    url: 'http://www.google.com/'
        //},
        //{
        //    title: 'Meeting all day - 1',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, d),
        //    allDay: true,
        //    url: 'http://www.google.com/'
        //},
        //{
        //    title: 'Meeting all day - 2',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, d),
        //    allDay: true,
        //    url: 'http://www.google.com/'
        //},
        //{
        //    title: 'Meeting all day - 3',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, d),
        //    allDay: true,
        //    url: 'http://www.google.com/'
        //},
        //{
        //    title: 'Meeting all day - 3',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, d),
        //    allDay: true,
        //    url: 'http://www.google.com/'
        //},
        //{
        //    title: 'Meeting all day - 4',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, d),
        //    allDay: true,
        //    url: 'http://www.google.com/'
        //},
        //{
        //    title: 'Meeting all day - 5',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, d),
        //    allDay: true,
        //    url: 'http://www.google.com/'
        //},
        //{
        //    title: 'Meeting all day - 6',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, d),
        //    allDay: true,
        //    url: 'http://www.google.com/'
        //},
        //{
        //    title: 'Birthday Party',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
        //    end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
        //    allDay: false
        //},
        //{
        //    title: 'Click for Google 112233',
        //    start: new Date(y, m, 28),
        //    end: new Date(y, m, 29),
        //    url: 'http://google.com/'
        //}
        //]
    });
};   //}();                  
</script>
</html>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        setDetails();
    }
}
protected void setDetails()
{
    lblCaption.Text = string.Format("{0}", DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text).ToString("MMM/yyyy"));        
}
protected void DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //setDetails();
}
public string[] GetData()
{
    string[] data = new string[5];
    data[0] = "title: 'All Day Event 2',start: new Date(y, m, 1)";
    data[1] = @"title: 'Meeting all day',start: new Date(y, m, 2),allDay: true,url: 'http://www.google.com/'";
    data[2] = @"title: 'Meeting all day - 1',start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),allDay: true,url: 'http://www.google.com/'";
    data[3] = @"title: 'Birthday Party',start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 12, 0),end: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),allDay: false";
    data[4] = @"title: 'Click for Google 112233',start: new Date(y, m, 28),end: new Date(y, m, 9),url: 'http://google.com/' ";
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I managed to figured out the problem. Refer to FullCalendar site https://fullcalendar.io/ documentation for further details. Thank your.

Comment: If you found the answer please post it here (in the "Answers" section, below) so others can benefit from it! That is why this site exists. You can also benefit too, if it causes you to receive upvotes...